# How do I mock a flask decorator @login_required for my unit tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, flask-testing

I am working on an application which requires a few unit tests to be written. I wanted to ask how can I mock a decorator '@login_required' in my unit tests?
here is a function which has the @login_required function in app.py

```
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    global application_inst
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Setting changed")

    return render_template('settings.html', user=session['user'], application=application_inst)
```

and here is my unit testcase in test_app.py

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(db)
        self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True
        self.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        self.app.config['DEBUG'] = True
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

    def test_settings_passed(self):
        with self.client:
            response = self.client.get('/settings', follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Since there was no way for me to get the test passed ie. status_code = 200 as it expects 404. I have tried everything available on the internet and it didn't solve my issue. Hence I wanted to try mocking the decorator. How can I do it?
Please help me as I am stuck in this problem since long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using the decorator from `flask_login`.

It's not really possible to post-hoc mock a decorator, because its decoration has already taken place. That said, you can look at [what the decorator does](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/3eb30a2ceb507a5e1e171844f213d799d1158e73/flask_login/utils.py#L267) in order to find out how to mock it.

As you can see in the source, there's a bunch of cases where the login won't be enforced:

```
if request.method in EXEMPT_METHODS:
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
elif current_app.config.get('LOGIN_DISABLED'):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
    return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can:

- mock `EXEMPT_METHODS` to include `GET` and `POST`.
- mock the `LOGIN_DISABLED` config value
- mock `current_user.is_authenticated`

Comment: As I have already set login_disabled to True in my setUp() function is there a need to mock the login_disabled config value again?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.